# Querying an array instead of range

Tags: google-sheets

`=QUERY({"key", "val"; "a", 2; "b", 3; "c", 1; "a", 2}, "SELECT * WHERE A = 'a'")`

This gives the `NO_COLUMN: A` error. Is there a way to make it work? The data in my real world sheet comes from a custom function so it can't be a range of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUERY calls to virtual arrays use `Colx` notation, e.g.:

`=QUERY({"key", "val"; "a", 2; "b", 3; "c", 1; "a", 2}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = 'a'")`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Couldn't find that info anywhere.

Comment: Glad I was able to provide it. And because you've taken the step of marking the solution as "Best Answers," future visitors to the site will be able to find it more easily.